# What is the best automated ETL method to transfer data from SQL Server IN cloud (AWS) to SQL Server NOT in Cloud?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, etl

We have 2 SQL Server databases. One of them is to be moved to AWS cloud.

1. Is Amazon RDS the ONLY approach to move the SQL Server to AWS?
2. What is the best way to automate data transfer of table data from the SQL Server that IS in the cloud to the SQL Server that is NOT in the cloud?

The volume and complexity of data is not high in our case. We need to migrate only ONE table and we'd like to automate it to run every night.

Would AWS Glue be useful for this? Would it help in loading data from INSIDE the cloud to OUTSIDE?

I also just found DMS - https://aws.amazon.com/dms/

But the homepage says "Migrate your databases `**to**` AWS with minimal downtime"

Can I do the opposite with DMS? Can I migrate data `**FROM**` AWS to outside AWS?

Comment: Do you prefer a "push" from on-premises approach or a "pull' from the cloud approach? Do all required tables have a primary key? You could always try sql repllication

Comment: Push or pull - either should be fine I guess. Would AWS Glue help? Could you provide any resourceful links for SQL replication pls? Can it be automated?

Comment: I'll leave you to google SQL replication. Looks like AWS glue is an ETL tool which means you'll need to do more custom work top get what you want. It really depends how many rows you have and how many tables. If you have 10 tables with <10,000 rows each you can just delete and reload every time.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - thanks! Will SQL replication work if I need to automate data replication from SQL Server INSIDE the cloud to SQL Server OUTSIDE the cloud?

Comment: Maybe. You’d have to try. It looks like MDS is a wrapper for replication anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. Amazon RDS is not the only approach to host SQLServer in the cloud. You can use an EC2 instance and install SQLServer manually. This could make sense in case you want to have sys_admin privileges. But be careful, as you would have to do patching all by yourself. I would not recommend doing that.
2. DMS is a good way to migrate your data every night. The service you are looking for is continuous data replication from DMS. Glue can also be used for this task. Glue's purpose was never to do database replication. Hence, it could be a pain monitoring the replication & debug in case of errors. That is why I would recommend DMS.